# SQL - Insert multiple categories to column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I store products, and in the same table I store the ID of the category I want the product to be in.

My product table looks like this:

```
id | product_name | category_id | price
```

And then I have my category table:

```
id | category
```

My problem is to know how I can insert multiple categories into my category_id, and if it is possible.

If not, whats the best way that I could do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible but you really don't want to go there. Storing multiple values in a single datarow column is a terrible idea in 99.99999% of the cases.

For more information, read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

What you want to do is to add another table to store the relationship between the products and the categories. This is referred to as a many to many relationship.

This new table should hold the product id in one column and the category id in the other one, and have a composite primary key that is the combination of both these columns.

This way, you can have many products in the same category, and many categories for the same product.

Comment: Yes! I read the reference and i should had known that wasn't a good ideia. In terms of the solution, is much more simple and i will implement it right away. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `many to many` relationship, which mean you need a third table let's call it `ProductCategories`, in this case you will have

- Products

  ```
  id | product_name | category_id | price
  ```
- Category

  ```
  id | category
  ```
- ProductCategories

  ```
    PruductID | CategoryID (combined PK)
  ```